# Multiple instances of SessionscopedBean & @observes

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm using wildfly and have a problem with EJB events and @Observes annotation.

I have an @ApplicationScoped bean, which is instanciated twice. Any idea why?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class WmsUiCodeService implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3051136197752781297L;

    ....

    @Override
    public void handleChangeEvent(@Observes MychangeEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I use it once from a sessionScoped bean and once from a resquestScoped bean:

```
@Inject
private UiCodeService uiCodeService;
```

My first problem is that i have 2 instances of this bean and the second is that the handleChangeEvent is called just in one of those two instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It comes from the annotation which came from

```
javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped
```

if i use the one in

```
javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
```

than is everything ok.